# Delete text between parentheses, but never past empty line

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, perl

Consider a text file, with lines of text gathered in many blocks, where each block is separated by at least one empty line. Using a Bash one-liner, how do I delete all text from `<` to either `>` or `\n\n`?

To put it differently: Delete everything between each pair of `<` and `>`. If a `<`has no closing `>`, delete everything until the end of the block (an empty line), but *never, ever* delete outside the block!

Conceptually, should I physically separate the blocks into objects in a list before parsing for safety, or is this a straight forward linear text parsing job as long as you know what you are doing?

Example text:

```
This is the first
block of text.
                             <-- empty line
<delete me>
This is the second block.
<delete
here>
<delete this, but
                             <-- empty line
do not delete this>
<delete this too>
Third block here.

(more blocks)
```

The result should be:

```
This is the first
block of text.
                             <-- empty line
This is the second block.
                             <-- empty line
do not delete this>
Third block here.
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "empty line"? Is that meant to be a literal empty line where you say `...(empty line)`? Or do you just mean a line without a `>`? If the former, perhaps just edit the question to show a literal empty line; we will understand.

Comment: are non-perl solutions acceptable?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: I can easily solve it with some lines of PHP, but I'm looking for something short and UNIX-y that fits snugly inside a Bash script.

Comment: is this okay? `awk -v RS= -v ORS= '{gsub(/<[^>]+>?/, "")}1'` doesn't preserve the empty lines but newline character after `>` remains.. so may not suit for your real sample

Comment: @Sundeep: The newlines have to be preserved. They are holy dividers that define the boundaries of the blocks, so to speak.

Comment: You got it almost right: it should be `perl -0777pe 's/<.*?(>|(?=\n\n))//sg'`

Comment: @forthrin in that case, could you add more samples for testing? or tell if `awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n' '{gsub(/<[^>]+>?\n?/, "")}1'` is good enough?

Answer (score 1):

Try awk's paragraph mode:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '{gsub(/<[^>]+>?\n?/, "")}1' ip.txt 
This is the first
block of text.

This is the second block.


do not delete this>
Third block here.
```

- `-v RS=` this will cause one or more consecutive empty lines to be used as input record separator
- `-v ORS='\n\n'` set output record separator as two newline characters
- `gsub(/<[^>]+>?\n?/, "")` delete `<` followed by non `>` characters followed by optional `>` and newline characters
- `1` idiomatic way to print input record contents

Same thing with `perl`

```
perl -00 -lpe 'BEGIN{$\="\n\n"} s/<[^>]+>?\n?//g' ip.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU **`Awk`** solution:

```
awk -v RS='[<>]' '/\n\n/{ sub(/^[^\n]+\n/, ""); print $0 RT }' file
```

- `RS='[<>]'` - treat `<` and `>` as record separator
- `/\n\n/` - if current record contains 2 linebreaks:

  - `sub(/^[^\n]+\n/, "")` - remove everything till the 1st newline (inclusive)
  - `print $0 RT` - print current record followed by `RT` (i.e. `>`)
  - `RT` - the  record terminator. `Gawk` sets `RT` to the input text that matched the character or regular expression specified by `RS`.

---

The output:

```
<empty line>   
don't delete this>
```